# regarding the meaning of a phrase

Tags: phrases

what is the meaning of the following phrase?

*once too often*

like **he did it once too often**

Thanks in anticipation.

Answer (score 1):

The phrase 'Once too often' is used to say that someone has done something wrong or stupid again, and this time they will suffer due to it.